# Re-prompting User for required Facebook permissions using Firebase auth if denied some permissions initially

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to request facebook permissions again using Firebase auth, if user chooses to decline some of the permissions first time around?

It seems even If I delete the user and then run firebase Oauth again, the permissions selection is never shown to the user.

**UPDATE:**

Current Workaround is Calling `axios` Delete call like so:

```
axios.delete(`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/me/permissions?access_token=${accessToken}`)
```

to delete my app from Users facebook account. and calling Firebase Auth again for Facebook.

Comment: which platform are you talking about? web or mobile ?

Comment: Web in my case.